# Sync data between Android App and Chrome App using Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-chrome-app

I want to write a small Android App and also a small Google Chrome App, which should keep their data synchronized. I decided to use Google Drive to synchronize the data.

Like Google Keep [seems to do it](http://www.steegle.com/google-products/google-keep-faq#TOC-How-do-I-access-my-Google-Keep-notes-) :

> Google Keep saves all your notes to your Google Drive, so everything is backed up and available, should anything happen to the original device or computer on which the notes were made.

Currently I am only working on the Android App. After searching for a way to create a hidden folder to store the data I found the [Application Folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/appdata).

While this seems to be perfect for my Android App my question is: can I also access this app folder from a google chrome app?

If not is there a good way to synchronize data between an Android App and a Chrome App using Google Drive?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What has your research told you so far? Have you prototyped a client using the Google Drive API and run into a specific issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"question is: can I also access this app folder from a google chrome app?"**

yes

**"If not is there a good way to synchronize data between an Android App and a Chrome App using Google Drive?"**

There are numerous sync strategies you can employ, eg ...

- Full refresh
- Poll changes feed
- Set up a push notification

Which is right for you depends on your specific preferences

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome Apps for Mobile (using the `cca` tool)](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps) have an implementation of [chrome.syncFileSystem](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/tree/master/chrome-cordova/plugins/chrome.syncFileSystem) that will use Drive storage to sync data between a chrome desktop and hybrid android app automatically for you!

The downside is that `chrome.syncFileSystem` does not currently use Drive Application Data folder (it wasn't available when we implemented the API).

The upside is, if you only care about syncing data, and not necessarily *how* it is synced, and you already want to implement a chrome app anyway, using the `cca` tool should really be an awesome solution for you.